Bathroom fan venting options
My house was built in 1978 and the bathroom fan has always been vented into the attic. I am looking to fix that but struggling with where to vent it. I would like to avoid venting through the roof if possible. I have a gable end but it is on the front corner of the house and there is vented soffit above it. This is about a 15 foot straight shot from the bathroom fan. I have also looked at venting out the soffit but my soffit is angled, the only decent vents I have found require flat soffit to work properly. Is my best option to vent out the front of the house in the corner? Or any better options I am missing? Pictures attached in the link below.
https://imgur.com/a/1YoPCQx

Seems like you could easily vent through the eaves/soffits, no?  I don't see that them being angled would be too much of a barrier, aside from needing appropriate bends in the ducting.  Is that the bathroom in question in the last photo (gable end + window)?

Bathroom is on the side wall. First photo on the right hand side, to the right of the window. The corner of the house is a bedroom. The soffit vents I have found all have a door to prevent backdraft, but it seems that these are all designed to be on a 90* angle so they open and shut properly.

How about a wall mount fan?

@Ben - Just wanted to comment how beautiful your grass is and love how you have the rocks on the side of the house - very nice.

Thanks @JonH! I appreciate that. The house has come a long ways since we purchased it 7 years ago. There were bushes taller than the roof line at that time.

If your fan discharges out the side, the 15' run to the gable would be my choice. No 90 degree bends and use rigid duct for maximum flow.
Honestly, in my opinion, going through the roof is not as bad as everyone makes it sound, especially if you have a shingle roof. Bathroom fans work best with short duct runs and shooting straight up through the roof is usually the shortest run. Cutting the hole and sealing the opening is not that hard and can be easier than crawling around in an attic.

Gable even though it is in the front of the house? My wife is concerned about this for aesthetic purposes. My thought was to look for a white, low profile vent and drill it into the white trim, least noticeable going that route. Going out the roof - Would you still use rigid duct for that?

@Ben  The most important concern is keeping the wife happy.  You should be able to easily find a low profil, flat soffit vent, white, at your home store.  As far as going through the roof, if it is a short, straight run,  you can use ridid, PVC or flexible metal pulled tight.  Even on longer runs with rigid, PVC,  you'll usually need a small section of flexible to ease the replacement of the fan inth future unless you'll always have easy access to the attic.

+1 on the roof option.  The key is that the vent flashing works with the shingles.  For sure, it's something you need to make sure is done correctly, though.

Thanks all! The roof option does seem like a better answer than the other two possibilities. I do have easy access to the attic. I also like my marriage so wife happiness is the #1 priority! Eric commented and mentioned a J-vent. Seems like a better option than some of the low profile mounts (I am in a snow state). Otherwise, would a plumbing style PVC vent with a 180 degree bend at the top work for a bathroom fan? Or isn't that recommended?

@Ben  A PVC 180 degree bend, 2- 90 degrees,  would reduce the flow quite a bit whereas a roof mounted J vent cap would not.  Check your home stores. They probably have some made by Broan specifically for this.

I'm a building inspector with over 26 years of experience inspecting residential homes and commercial buildings. I agree with Mark's answer, I would go with a simple J-vent on the roof. It's very simple to install (by a roofing contractor), and they are not prone to leakage. You already have several vents going through your roof, you would have your plumbing vent (aka: "stink pipe"), and your outflow vents (Maximum vents, "mushroom caps", etc). A J-vent is just another vent, flashed the same as other vents and roof protrusions. If you're doing it yourself, take care to make sure the flashing collar extends under the shingles running above and beside the J-vent.
If you don't want to go with a J-vent, I think the issue you're having with a soffit vent is the angle that the flexduct would have to make where it connects to the four-inch coupler on the backside of the soffit vent? The coupler would be angled towards the eave, so your flexduct would have a wicked bend in it right at the eave, which is not ideal. Also, it appears you have 2x4 rafters, so a std 4" flexduct wouldn't even fit, let alone the extra space for the bend/elbow. So I would go with the end gable if you don't want to go with a J-vent. 15' is not too far of a run for a bathroom fan.
Hope that helps.

Thanks Eric! Appreciate the response. I've looked at a few options for roof mounted vents/caps. I am in Michigan so have to deal with snow. Should I look at a roof vent with some height (Quick google search says some J Vents can come with 6+" clearances). I've seen a few other styles that only come up a couple inches off the roof. If that gets buried by snow, will that cause issues with fan exhaust?

I ended up finding this company PreVent-It who makes an extended soffit vent that extends to the very edge of the roofline and dumps exhaust air next to the roof instead of underneath the soffit. Made for an easier install and a much shorter run (~5 feet) from the fan to the vent. Install image here - Imgur. Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions!

Hi Ben, I'm so sorry I didn't realize you had answered me back in September! Anyway, I'm glad to hear you found an adequate solution, and thanks for showing me your solution, I'll definitely keep PreVent-It in mind for future clients with similar issues.
